# what is best way server static files

Tags: wordpress, nginx, content-management-system, static-files

I was reading on the net about to produce static files and how to keep them at max age so that I can use them whenever a request is made through the server. Basically, I have a community forum **www.mycommunity.com** that works on Nginx and want to server static files from cookieless domain which is **http://mycommunity.com.net**. I went trying to find the best ways on how to server static files so I ran into CMS platforms and reading about how to use them. The interesting part was that each CMS platform has some plugins that I can run to server the static files to another domain. I noticed that wordpress is the easiest to setup and deal with, but most its plugins are not compatible with Nginx. Sounds like WP super cache and W3TC plugins are best to achieve my goal, but yet unsure if I'm on the right way to do that...

I consider light weight "low memory usage" ways to do that at priority though.

any suggestion or comment on that??

Thanks

Comment: If you look around you'll find that most these plugins already have in their docs an nginx rewrite you can add in your server, or someone who answered someone who's asking about that rewrite.

Comment: ok, I think I got the point. Thanks a lot